# Third-level domains with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to do a thing like that used in basecamp.com: the name of your company becomes a third-level domain, http://mycompany.basecamp.com for example. I understand that it is (most likely) made ​​on the basis of .htaccess file and mod_rewrite, but I do not quite understand how exactly. Please advise me how it is implemented? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

1. Create the subdirectory inside htdocs: `/host/users/myaccount/htdocs/mycompany` or equivalent
2. Back up the .htaccess , is always better
3. Add the following lines to `.htaccess` file:

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mycompany\.basecamp\.com
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mycompany/?
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mycompany/$1 [L]
> ```

This will catch every call to the third level domain and answer with files from the subfolder

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I need that a subdomain redirect to a specific page of the wordpress site. Thanks!+1

Comment: with my Apache setup (2.4.46-1 on  current Debian sid) I need to add a whitespace in the second RewriteCond line between the closig curly brace and the exclamation mark, otherwise I get a syntax error