# Redirect third level domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

This seems easy enough but I can't seem to find the exact solution online and to get it to work.  I want to redirect all the links e.g.

```
user1.example.com
user2.example.com
user3.example.com etc.
```

to

```
example.com/search.html?user=user1
example.com/search.html?user=user2
example.com/search.html?user=user3 etc.
```

in my .htaccess I have

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?example.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([\.]+)\.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* /search.html?user=% [L]
```

I want to redirect all the user "subdomains" (they don't really exist on the server) except if the domain is prefix with www.  The "user" field consists of alphabets, numeric, - (dash), _ (underscore) and possibly space.  I am getting the *Server Not Found* error with the above .htaccess with for example, `user1.example.com`   What am I doing wrong? Can this be done without the real existence of these third level domains?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* /search.html?user=%1 [R,L]
```

Comment: I have thousands of users so the rewrite needs to be generic.

Comment: Same server not found issue :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use negative lookahead in your condition while capturing first part of domain and use the back-reference as `%1` later:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www\.)[^.]+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^search\.html$ /search.html?user=%1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Do you mean `Server Not Found` error? **Server Not Found** means your domain isn't a valid domain and has no DNS entry.

Comment: The domain exists of course.  But the third level domains don't actually exist.  I have made the links of user accounts to look like the third level domains.  When the link is clicked, I want them to be redirected to the search.html instead.

Comment: All those `user1.example.com` or `user2.example.com` also have to resolve to a valid IP first. Test with `nslookup` or `dig` first.

Comment: user1.example.com etc. don't really exist.  Does that mean I cannot rewrite with .htaccess?  If they exist, there is no point for me to rewrite.

Comment: If DNS cannot be resolved for a host then request won't even reach to your webserver.

Comment: example.com exists.  Wouldn't DNS be resolved?  I have found one similar [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11887544/third-level-domains-with-htaccess) this so I think it may be possible

Comment: `http://wikipedia.org/` exists and a valid domain now try: `http://qwerty.wikipedia.org/` and see what happens.

Comment: It won't work because they didn't do a rewrite for the qwerty.wikipedia.org  I think you may be missing the point.  If I have those third level domains created, I wouldn't need to do a rewrite.

Comment: Rewrite happens only after DNS is resolved. `http://qwerty.wikipedia.org/` results in DNS error so forget rewrite/redirect.